# Given an aspect ratio, calculate an int width that will result in an int height

Tags: php, image, math

Given an image ratio such as 1.5001489425082, how to calculate the minimum possible width that is always an int, not a float, and that, respecting the ratio, results in a height that is always an int aswell ?

I am trying to create image placeholders on the fly and I came out with this code (uses kirby cms chain syntax, but pretty self-explanatory):

```
<img src="<?= $file->resize(10,(10/$file->ratio()))->url() ?>"
```

... I resize() the `$file`, using `10` as width, and `(10/$file-ratio())` as height. But this sometimes results in floating point numbers, which won't do as we are working here with pixels.

Thus the question about being able to choose the minimum width that is an int, and that will result in a height that is also an int ALWAYS.

Thank you

Comment: Float values are approximate so strictly speaking the information you want is lost. You need the width w and height h, then you can just divide both by gcd(w,h).

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, but, what is "gcd" in your comment?

Comment: Greatest Common Divisor https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor

Comment: Oh, of course, as in php gmp_gcd() , would you like to write an answer ? thanks!

Comment: If the image dimensions are say not more than in the thousands, and you have a double precision float of their ratio, you could probably obtain with reasonable accuracy the values for w/gcd(w,h) and h/gcd(w,h) by looking for the smallest errors (distances from whole numbers) you get as you try every possible integer width or height. It would be better to just get them from w and h though if possible.

Answer (score 1):

If an image has integer width and height, w and h respectively then being given only an approximate float value of their ratio is not enough information to reliably obtain the lowest integer width and height values you're looking for. If you know w and h, the they can be made as small as possible while keeping them both integers and maintaining the same ratio by dividing by their Greatest Common Divisor gcd(w,h).